# Google forms get score of respondent's answer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I write google forms add-on for statistical analysis of responses (average, median, standard deviation, discriminative efficiency and so on).

Is it possible to get score of user's answer from gs code? Or maybe exists the method for checking user's response?

Answer (score 2):

please research before asking. Just a quick glimpse at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form) shows the entry for `getResponses()` which shows what you can do with the [formResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) object. As you can see you can get every single part of the response.

Comment: in the documentation they have mentioned all the functions which we can use. But in my case also itemResponse.getScore() returning null on formSubmit. Please provide a simple working example for getscore on google form submission.

Comment: Also getting null. Any ideas why?