# Google Forms Script ItemResponse getScore() returns null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

Not sure if it is a bug or not, but the `getScore()` method (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getscore) always returns `null` for me, while it is said it should return a `double`.

The form **is** a Quiz, **does** accept answers, the score is set to `2` to all questions, the score **is** being registered in the responses in the Google Form.

```js
// Code.gs

function onOpen (e) {
  setOnSubmitTrigger();
}

function setOnSubmitTrigger () {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger(respondToFormSubmit)
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

function respondToFormSubmit (e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var allResponses = form.getResponses();
  var response = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();

  console.log(form.isQuiz()); // yields true

  for (var i in itemResponses) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];

    Logger.log(itemResponse.getScore()); // (!) always yields null
  }
}
```

The topic is mentioned in the following questions, but they are neither focused specifically on the issue, nor provide a solution:

- [How to check if a response is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751071/how-to-check-if-a-response-is-correct)
- [Google forms get score of respondent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090468/google-forms-get-score-of-respondents-answer)

Comment: How are you testing your script? Have you created a [mcve]?

Comment: Related: [Google script to get averaged scores and emails from Google Forms (as Quiz)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47982868/1595451)

Comment: @Rubén thank you, I edited the code snippet as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is documented in Google Script Reference, but here is a solution:

```js
// Code.gs

// ...

function respondToFormSubmit (e) {
  // ...
  var itemResponses =
    response.getGradableItemResponses(); // NOT .getItemResponses()

  console.log(form.isQuiz()); // yields true

  for (var i in itemResponses) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];

    Logger.log(itemResponse.getScore()); // yields number!
  }
}
```